# syntax for passing user defined type variable to function in vba

Tags: vba, function, types

I have defined a Type:

```
Type JobData
    r_j As Integer
End Type
```

I have a variable assigned as the Type JobData:

```
Dim job_data() As JobData
```

I wrote a function:

```
Function sumReady(a1 As JobData, a2 As Integer) As Integer
sumReady = a1(0).r_j

For j = 1 To job_ct
   sumReady = job_data(j).r_j + sumReady
Next

End Function
```

But when I try to call the function, I get a syntax error.

```
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Value = sumReady(job_data().r_j, job_ct)
```

(job_ct is defined as an Integer)

What am I doing wrong?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function refers to both the variable containing the argument (`a1`) and the instance of the `JobData` datatype (`job_data`); similarly with `a2` and `job_ct`. You should just refer to `a1` and `a2`, i.e.:

```
Function sumReady(a1 As JobData, a2 As Integer) As Integer
    sumReady = a1(0).r_j

    For j = 1 To a2
        sumReady = a1(j).r_j + sumReady
    Next

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a property of the data type not the actual data type that is the error, the call should be `ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Value = sumReady(job_data, job_ct)`

Comment: I've tried doing that but then I get a "ByRef argument type mismatch".  Thoughts?